# Adding event participants to SharePoint group calendar via web service API

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, calendar, caml

I want to programmatically add an event to a group calendar in SharePoint 2010 via the web service API.

This is what I already did:

```
        service = new SharePointListsService.Lists();
        service.PreAuthenticate = true;
        service.Url = "http://sharepoint/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");

        elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");

        string strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
            "<Field Name='Title'>New Test</Field>" +
            "<Field Name='Description'>New Description</Field>" +
            "<Field Name='Location'>TestTitle1</Field>" +
            "<Field Name='EventDate'>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Field>" +
            "<Field Name='EndDate'>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Field>" +
            "<Field Name='Category'>My Category</Field>" +
            "<Field Name='fAllDayEvent'>1</Field>" +
            //  @"<Field Name='Participants'>Domain\Username<Field>" +
            "</Method>";

        elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
        var returnValue = service.UpdateListItems("MyList", elBatch);
```

How can I add a participant (Attendee) to the event?
I tried adding them like this:

```
           @"<Field Name='Participants'>Domain\Username<Field>"
```

But this does not work.
If I execute the code above, an event will be created (as intended). But I do not know how to add participants to the events.

Greetings

Alexander